# Finding the cause of abnormally large accelerations in my PyOpenCl-based N-Body simulation

Tags: python, pyopencl

My friend and I have been creating a Python based N-Body simulation, with the aim of simulating the solar system or galaxies. Our code uses PyOpenCl to access OpenCl parallel computation and PyQtGraphs to plot the simulation. We are also using the Astropy library to initialise the objects in our simulation with the correct velocities and positions.

Most of the code I show here is in the calc.py section of our simulation. This is where we feed our kernels the initial positions/velocities, retrieve the outputs and input them back into the kernels.

In the following, we set up the PyOpenCl code.

```
        self.cmdqueue = cl.CommandQueue(self.cntxt)
        self.bodytype = np.dtype([("velocity", cltypes.double3),("position", cltypes.double3),("mass", cltypes.double), ("acceleration", cltypes.double3), ("deltax", cltypes.double3), ("trace", cltypes.int)])
        self.bodytype, body_c = cl.tools.match_dtype_to_c_struct(self.cntxt.devices[0], "body", self.bodytype)
        self.bodytype = cl.tools.get_or_register_dtype("body", self.bodytype)
```

Then we create the calculation program that runs on the kernels. We give each kernel a single object, then - using the positions of the other objects - it calculates the new positions and velocities for this object. The numerical method we are using is a Velocity Verlet integrator (on which more information you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration).

It was when we first implemented this Velocity Verlet that our program started outputting large accelerations. Prior to this we were using the Euler method, which seemed to be operating normally. For the simulation of the Earth around the sun, our distance unit is Astronomical Units (AU) and our time unit is days (d),

```
__kernel void frst_prog(double delta, __global body *in,int len, __global body *outbodies,__global double3* outpositions, __global double3* outpositionsOld, __global double3* outaccelerations, __global double3* outaccelerationsOld)
             {
                // const double G = 6.67408 * pow(10.0, -11.0); // Normal G
                const double G = 1.4881361162906675 * pow(10.0, -34); // Solar System G
                //const double G = 1.42458 * pow(10.0, -22.0); // Galactic G
                int i  = get_global_id(0);
                body current = in[i];

                double3 vOld = current.velocity;
                double3 posOld = current.position;
                double3 oldAcc = findForces(len, in, current) * G;
                current.position = current.position + (vOld * delta) + (oldAcc * (delta * delta * 0.5));
                double3 acc = findForces(len, in, current) * G;
                current.velocity = vOld + ((acc + oldAcc) * (delta * 0.5));

                outbodies[i] = current;
                outpositions[i] = current.position;
                outpositionsOld[i] = posOld;
                outaccelerations[i] = acc;
                outaccelerationsOld[i] = oldAcc;
                }


            double3 findForces(int len,__global body *in, body current) {
                double3 forces["""  +  str(self.numThings) + """];
                for(int j = 0; j<len; j++){
                    body new = in[j];
                    double3 displacement = new.position - current.position;
                    double dist = length(displacement);

                    if(dist == 0.f){
                        //forces[j] = (double3)0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    forces[j] = ((new.mass)/(dist*dist))*(displacement/dist);
                    }

                double3 total = (double3)0;

                for(int j = 0; j<len; j++){
                    total += forces[j];
                }

                return total;
            }""").build()
```

We then handle the outputs and prepare the next calculation. Apologies for the long list of inputs into `launch = self.prg.frst_prog()`, a few of them are being used to debug the program. calcRepeats = 1 for the debugging process.

```
def update(self, delta, calcRepeats, realRunTime):
        delta = np.double(delta)
        for i in range(calcRepeats):
            launch = self.prg.frst_prog(self.cmdqueue, self.bodies.shape, None, delta, self.bodies_buf.data, np.int32(self.numThings), self.bodies_buf.data, self.outPosBuf, self.outPosOldBuf, self.outAccBuf, self.outAccOldBuf)
            launch.wait()
            realRunTime += delta

        cl.enqueue_copy(self.cmdqueue, self.outpositions, self.outPosBuf).wait()
        cl.enqueue_copy(self.cmdqueue, self.outpositionsOld, self.outPosOldBuf).wait()
        cl.enqueue_copy(self.cmdqueue, self.outaccelerations, self.outAccBuf).wait()
        cl.enqueue_copy(self.cmdqueue, self.outaccelerationsOld, self.outAccOldBuf).wait()
        return self.outpositions, self.outpositionsOld, self.bodies_buf, realRunTime, self.outaccelerations, self.outaccelerationsOld
```

To test the program, I initialised the simulation with the Earth and the Sun only. When I ran the program, it calculated ridiculously large accelerations. 'Old pos' refers to the position of the object before the calculation. 'New pos' refers to the position after the calculation. 'Old acc' refers to the acceleration before the position changes. 'New acc' refers to the acceleration calculated using the new position. As you can see in the image, Old pos and New pos are identical and, while Old acc is feasible, New acc is far too large.

[Command line print-outs at the very beginning of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjVaR.png)

How can we find the cause of these large accelerations?

Comment: I do not see where you apply the gravitational constant in the force computation.